# js: loop through object and count occurrences strings and create a ranking from the occurrences

Tags: javascript, string, loops, object, count

I have an object with objects and i want to display a ranking of names which occurs the most.

like

1. John
2. Maria
3. Josh

this is my object:

```
let data = {
    "1111": {
      firstName: "john",
      lastName: "doe",
    },
    "1112": {
      firstName: "john",
      lastName: "doe",
    },
    "1113": {
      firstName: "maria",
      lastName: "dee",
    },
    "1114": {
      firstName: "john",
      lastName: "doe",
    },
    "1115": {
      firstName: "maria",
      lastName: "dee",
    },
    "1116": {
      firstName: "josh",
      lastName: "kek",
    },
    "1117": {
      firstName: "maria",
      lastName: "dee",
    },
    "1118": {
      firstName: "nick",
      lastName: "smith"
    }

  }
```

i tried things with a for in loop but i dont got it right... On stackoverflow i just examples with arrays and array methods but i need this for an object.

```
for (let key in data) {
    let firstFind = data[key]["firstName"]
    let firstCounter = 0

    if(data[key]["firstName"] = firstFind) {
        firstCounter++
    } else {
        let secondFind = data[key]["firstname"]
        let secondCounter = 0
        
        if(data[key]["firstName"] = secondFind) {
            secondCounter++
        }

        //...reproduce until there is no new name
        //this is where my limit is
            
    }
    


  }
```

The Code should loop trough all objects, count the names, and create a ranking of which name occurs the most. See example above

Comment: please add your code, you tried. what shcould happen with two or more same counts?

Comment: `Object.values()` + one of the [_"javascript group array of objects"_](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=javascript+group+array+of+objects+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web) answers + `.sort()`

Comment: Thank you, i will try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially use `Object.entries()` in-order to get an iterable array of `key value` pairs and then do something like this

```js
const data = {} // insert your object here
const dupes = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    const elem = dupes.find(x => x.firstName === value.firstName); // if there is an element in the array
    if (elem) elem.count = elem.count + 1; // increase count by 1
    else { 
    const dat = { firstName: value.firstName, lastName: value.lastName, count: 1 };
    dupes.push(dat); // initiating a new element with count 1
    }
}
const sortArr = dupes.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
console.log(sortArr[0]) // returns the element with highest count.
// in your case this would be the output
// {firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe', count: 3}

// update to get the list in order
const lbArr = [];
sortArr.forEach(x => lbArr.push(`${x.firstName} ${x.lastName} ${x.count}`))
console.log(lbArr.join('\n'))
```

P.S you can use `Object.values()` as well, i used `Object.entries()` in-case you want to assign the key to the dupes array.

Comment: Thank you very much!! is there any way i can modify this to get the second and third highest count?

Comment: @TimSchneider sortedArr is an array you can log sortedArr[1] for second value etc and so on

Comment: @TimSchneider actually wait ill make a code for that

Comment: @TimSchneider if it worked could you please consider marking it as a correct answer :D

Comment: This answer isn't correct. There are 2 names with the same highest count, but this only returns one of them. This doesn't take into account ties.

Comment: @Kinglish it does return the names with same values (tied)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: It just lists results in order of count. if the OP wants to find out who's in first place, they still need to run some other loop. Plus in your answer `console.log(sortArr[0]) // returns the element with highest count.` isn't accurate. There are more than one index with the highest count.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, which results in a readable object that considers ties. I will comment the code to make it readable. Here is the output from your data:

```
{ "first": [
    {"name": "john doe", "count": 3},
    {"name": "maria dee", "count": 3}
  ],
  "second": [
    {"name": "josh kek", "count": 1},
    { "name": "nick smith", "count": 1}
  ],
  "third": []
}
```

```js
let data = {
    "1111": { firstName: "john",lastName: "doe" },
    "1112": { firstName: "john",lastName: "doe" },
    "1113": { firstName: "maria",lastName: "dee" },
    "1114": { firstName: "john",lastName: "doe" },
    "1115": { firstName: "maria",lastName: "dee" },
    "1116": { firstName: "josh",lastName: "kek" },
    "1117": { firstName: "maria",lastName: "dee" },
    "1118": { firstName: "nick",lastName: "smith" }
  }

let ranking =
  // we want to iterate through the {firstName:...} in each object so we use Object.values()
  // but we can't iterate objects like this so we wrap it in Object.entries, which turns it into an array
  Object.entries(Object.values(data)
  // this first reduce function does the counting and sets up an object of {name: count}
  .reduce((b, {firstName,lastName}) => {
    let n = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    // setting up a counter and using the whole name as a key (there may be more than one JOhn)
    b[n] = b.hasOwnProperty(n) ? b[n] + 1 : 1;
    return b
  }, {}))
  // wrapped in Objct.entries, this is an array which we can sort
  .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
  // the last reduce transfers the sorted {name: count} object into first second and third arrays
  .reduce((b, a) => {
      let v = { name: a[0], count: a[1]},
        placed = false;
      // we iterate through first, second and third and fill them in
      ['first', 'second', 'third'].forEach(p => {
        if (!placed && ((b[p].length > 0 && b[p][0].count === a[1]) || b[p].length === 0)) {
          b[p].push(v);
          placed = true;
        }
      });
       return b
      }, {first: [], second: [], third: [] });

console.log(ranking)


// all that can be optimized to this:
Object.entries(Object.values(data).reduce((b, {firstName,lastName}) => {
    let n = firstName + ' ' + lastName;  b[n] = b.hasOwnProperty(n) ? b[n] + 1 : 1; return b;
  }, {})).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a).reduce((b, a) => {
      let v = { name: a[0], count: a[1]}, placed = false;
      ['first', 'second', 'third'].forEach(p => {
        if (!placed && ((b[p].length > 0 && b[p][0].count === a[1]) || b[p].length === 0)) {
          b[p].push(v); placed = true;
        }}); return b;
      }, {first: [], second: [], third: [] });
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple approach is to gather the counts into an object using `reduce`, take the entries of that object, and sort these by the counts:

```js
const namesByCount = (xs) =>
  Object.entries (Object .values (xs) .reduce (
    (a, {firstName}) => ((a [firstName] = (a [firstName] || 0) + 1), a), 
    {}
  )) .sort (([, a], [, b]) => b - a) //.map (([a]) => a)

let data = {1111: {firstName: "john", lastName: "doe"}, 1112: {firstName: "john", lastName: "doe"}, 1113: {firstName: "maria", lastName: "dee"}, 1114: {firstName: "john", lastName: "doe"}, 1115: {firstName: "maria", lastName: "dee"}, 1116: {firstName: "josh", lastName: "kek"}, 1117: {firstName: "maria", lastName: "dee"}, 1118: {firstName: "nick", lastName: "smith"}}

console .log (namesByCount (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you wanted just the names, you could uncomment the `.map` call.

There is a bit of trickiness in the use of the comma operator.  I prefer to work with expressions rather than statements.  But if it bothers you, you could do this instead:

```js
const namesByCount = (xs) =>
  Object.entries (Object .values (xs) .reduce (
    (a, {firstName}) => {
      a [firstName] = a [firstName] || 0
      a [firstName] += 1
      return a
    },
    {}
  )) .sort (([, a], [, b]) => b - a) //.map (([a]) => a)
```